# Displaying a dropdown list with onmousehover and hiding it with onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show a dropdown list that is hidden(with css) with js. So I used onmousehover to show the list when I hover over a button, but when my mouse is away, the list is still there. I used onmouseout to hide the list, but when my mouse is not on the button, the list is gone.
Basically I want to be able to hover over the button, see the dropdown and click on the items, which is not possible because these items become hidden as soon as my mouse is not over the button.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="dropdownfonts">
    <button id="dropdown" onmouseover="drop()" onmouseout="hide()">Fonts</button>
    <br>
    <button class="fonts">Times New Roman</button><br>
    <button class="fonts">Calibri</button><br>
    <button class="fonts">Arial</button>
</div>
```

And my js:

```
T = document.getElementsByClassName("fonts")

function hide(){
    for(i = 0; i < T.length; i++)
        T[i].style.display="none";
}

function drop() {
    for( i = 0; i < T.length; i++)
        T[i].style.display="block";
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the mouse events on the enclosing span not on the button itself. And on hover make their display property equal to inline-block instead of inline

```js
T=document.getElementsByClassName("fonts")
for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)
T[i].style.display="none";

function hide(){
for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)
T[i].style.display="none";
}
function drop(){

for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)

T[i].style.display="inline-block";
}
```

```html
<span class="dropdownfonts" onmouseout="hide()" onmouseover="drop()">
<button id="dropdown"  
>Fonts</button>

<br>

<button class="fonts">Times New Roman</button><br>
<button class="fonts">Calibri</button><br>
<button class="fonts">Arial</button>


</span>

<br>
```

```js
 T=document.getElementsByClassName("fonts")
    for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)
    T[i].style.display="none";

    function hide(){
    for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)
    T[i].style.display="none";
    }
    function drop(){

    for(i=0;i<T.length;i++)

    T[i].style.display="inline-block";
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropdownfonts" onmouseout="hide()" onmouseover="drop()"> <button id="dropdown"  >Fonts</button> <br> <button class="fonts" value="2" onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Times New Roman</button><br> <button class="fonts" value="1" onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Calibri</button><br> <button class="fonts" value="3" onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Arial</button> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you all ! What you're saying is very logical, yet when I tried it, it doesn't seem to work :/ When I move my mouse away from the button, the dropdown hides. Here's the code: <div class="dropdownfonts" onmouseout="hide()">
<button id="dropdown" onmouseover="drop()" >Fonts</button>
 
<br>

 <button class="fonts" value="2" onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Times New Roman</button><br>
 <button class="fonts" value="1" onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Calibri</button><br>
    <button class="fonts" value="3" onclick="change(this.innerHTML)">Arial</button>

</div>

Comment: First of all use the drop() function with the div also. Div will take the width of the widest button by default so to overcome that you can use span so your mousehover range will get limited to the button only.

Comment: Check the other snippet i created in the answer.

Comment: It worked fine when I did that and changed div to span! Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the button which opens the dropdown *and* the dropdown items in an (invisible) contained, and then apply the same logic you have on it.

```
+-A----------------+
|                  |
| +-B------------+ |
| |              | |
| +--------------+ |
|                  |
| +-C------------+ |
| |              | |
| +--------------+ |
|                  |
| +-D------------+ |
| |              | |
| +--------------+ |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

`A` is the container, `B` is the button and `C` and `D` are items.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `onmouseover="drop()"` on `<div class="dropdownfonts">`